# Micronaut eager initialization of beans in test environment result in an error

Tags: micronaut

I have a @MicronautTest annotated class that eagerly load all beans using a custom ApplicationContextBuilder.

`@MicronautTest(contextBuilder = EagerInitSingletonsApplicationContextBuilder)`

This is the custom ApplicationContextBuilder

```
class EagerInitSingletonsApplicationContextBuilder extends DefaultApplicationContextBuilder {

    EagerInitSingletonsApplicationContextBuilder() {
        eagerInitSingletons(true)
    }

}
```

Using this, the test fails with and "initializationError" when Micronaut trying to inject any HttpClient. The error message is: "Retrieving the port from the server before it has started is not supported when binding to a random port".

I'm using Micronaut 3.1.4 and Netty.

In the past, this worked. After some changes or upgrade has stopped.

How can I resolve the problem?

P.S: In the Micronaut docs I have found this:

> Retrieving the port from the Netty embedded server is no longer
> supported if the server is configured to bind to a random port and the server has not been started.

Need to change the web server?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: "Need to change the web server?" - No.  "I have a @MicronautTest annotated class that eagerly load all beans using a custom ApplicationContextBuilder" - Can you show the source for your `EagerInitSingletonsApplicationContextBuilder`?

Comment: I have added the class ContextBuilder. Do you have a random port for the test and an HttpClient injected in a bean? I think that the problem is in the HttpClient that cannot instantiate because at creation time the server is not running.

Comment: "Do you have a random port for the test and an HttpClient injected in a bean?" - If you are asking if that is supported, I think the answer is "yes".

Comment: In the next few days trying to share a sample project to replicate the problem...

Comment: "In the next few days trying to share a sample project to replicate the problem" - I created a sample for you at https://github.com/jeffbrown/francescorandomport.

Comment: This sample is similar to my case (https://github.com/fmonorchio/micronaut-test-httpclient).  Your test do not use eagerly loading and do not start on random port. These two are mandatory for me because, without eagerly load i do not see autowiring problem and the random port because i have multiple service and the tests are running in parallel.

Comment: "Your test do not use eagerly loading and do not start on random port." - I think it does both of those things.

Comment: Apologies.  The test was definitely running on a random port, but the test that enables eager singletones wasn't committed initially.  It is now at https://github.com/jeffbrown/francescorandomport/blob/5f045d391a4cfcce37020777e15b11ce1f881a6d/src/test/java/francescorandomport/DemoControllerTest.java.

Comment: Why is it that you don't think the tests are running the server on a random port?

Comment: The eargerly loading is commented. Now try your new push. On the random port i'm debugging your project and effectively is random. For me, i think that on production i have specified server.port=8080 and without overriding with -1 in application-test.yml use that 8080.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239682/discussion-between-francesco-and-jeff-scott-brown).